# Will this code create more objects than the ones I've explicitly created?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm

```
String startTime, endTime;
startTime = simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC_TIMEZONE)).getTime()); 
long time1 = System.nanoTime();

while (shouldRun) {
   endTime = simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(UTC_TIMEZONE)).getTime());

   long time2 = System.nanoTime();
   long pause = time2 - time1;

   if (pause > threshold) {
       LOG.info("Delay : {} ", pause);
   }

   time1 = time2;
   startTime = endTime
}
```

In my understanding, I'm creating only 2 objects of String types, but I'm not very confident of my java memory management knowledge. By the way, `shouldRun` is always true, this thread is responsible of collecting some performance data about the application with whom it shares the JVM.

I've updated the code, the aim of this thread is to keep running and to measure (`try to`) SafePoint pauses.

Comment: Why would it "leak memory"? Java uses a garbage collector.

Comment: A "memory leak" is where you hold on to objects you don't need.

Comment: You don't need the formatted times inside the loop at all. Produce them beforehand and afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell, because the code you posted doesn't make the scope clear.

Usually I see start and end times as long, not String.  Not useful in this form; can't calculate duration, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Any memory that you finish using will automatically be cleaned up by the garbage collector (unless you do things that confuse the garbage collector such as keeping references lying around that you don't need any more).

At the end of this example you have two `String` references, you have created two strings and put them in those references. Anything else used will be tidied up for you.